# Prevent Node-Inspector automatic reload when app crashes

Tags: node.js, node-inspector, nodemon

I've run into this problem several times now.  My node application crashes -nodemon outputs "app crashed - waiting for file changes..." and node-inspector automatically detects that the debug process has detached and so reloads.  Huge problem, because information in the node-inspector console is now lost to me.  Is there a way to stop the reload, other than to revert back to a much earlier version of node-inspector where the automatic reload wasn't present?